# Accessibility. media gallery. tab navigation.after

Tags: video, navigation, tabs, accessibility, focus

When i navigate with tab key, the focus goes to the first media, then to the next media. If the media is a video, the focus jump from the video to the video controls and after focus in all video controls, it jumps to the broser naviagtion bar. i want to fix 2 things.

1. when the focus is on the last video controls, i want, after pressing tab key, that the focus jump on <h3 class="article_media_container_card_likes> in order to increment the likes.
2. if the focus is on a picture, if i press tab, it jumps to the next media. I want that if the focus is on a picture, it jumps to the <h3 class="article_media_container_card_likes> in order to increment the likes.
   Above is the html part of the media gallery:

```
<article class="article_media" title="photographie de Wild horses in the mountains">
  <div class="article_media_container">
    <div class="article_media_container_card">
      
  <video class="article_media_container_card_video" controls="" onclick="displayLightBox(243, 5234343, 'Mimi')">
    <source src="./assets/media/Mimi/Animals_Wild_Horses_in_the_mountains.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  
      <div class="article_media_container_card_title_and_price">
        <h2 class="article_media_container_card_title">Wild horses in the mountains</h2>
        <h3 class="article_media_container_card_likes" onclick="incrementLike(this)" aria-label="j'aime">142 </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
<article class="article_media" title="photographie de Rainbow Bird">
  <div class="article_media_container">
    <div class="article_media_container_card">
      
  <img src="./assets/media/Mimi/Animals_Rainbow.jpg" alt="photo de Rainbow Bird" class="article_media_container_card_img" onclick="displayLightBox(243, 95234343, 'Mimi')">
  
      <div class="article_media_container_card_title_and_price">
        <h2 class="article_media_container_card_title">Rainbow Bird</h2>
        <h3 class="article_media_container_card_likes" onclick="incrementLike(this)" aria-label="j'aime">59 </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

i have tried different combinaison of tabindex but i did not succeed. i have tried with focus but it works only for the pictures, not the videos (with focus, i can jump properly from image to incrementlikes, then to the next image but if the next media in the gallery is a video, it daes not take the focus at all and jump to the first next picture).

Answer (score 0):

First you should get the roles right. A heading is not expected to be clicked or interacted with. You should use a `<button>` inside the `<h3>` to fix that.

But then, it shouldn’t be a heading in the first place. It’s simply a number of likes.

Currently, the `aria-label` is **overwriting** the element’s content *59*. You’d want to add that to the element’s accessible name.

```html
<h2>Wild horses in the mountains</h2>
<button onclick="incrementLike(this)" aria-label="59 likes. Like Wild horses in the mountains" aria-describedby="h2-1">59</button>
```

A real button will already have a tab stop, and also triggers the click handler on <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>. So this should achieve what you are looking for.

Screen reader users need to know which object they are going to like, especially if the headline structure is not clean. So adding the media’s name also is helpful.

### Headline structure

As most screen reader users mainly use headlines to navigate, the `<h2>` should come **before the video**. If you’d like to change order visually, you might use [`order` in a `flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order).

### Use `<figure>` for media items

The [`<figure>` element is intended for binding media together with a text]. I recommend using it, as it will also provide quick navigation to screen reader users:

> Assistive technologies SHOULD enable users to quickly navigate to figures. User agents MAY enable users to quickly navigate to figures.

— [`figure` in the ARIA standard](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#figure)

```html
<figure>
  <video class="article_media_container_card_video" controls="" onclick="displayLightBox(243, 5234343, 'Mimi')">
    <source src="./assets/media/Mimi/Animals_Wild_Horses_in_the_mountains.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  
      <figcaption class="article_media_container_card_title_and_price">
        <h2 …>Wild horses in the mountains</h2>
        <button …>52</button>
      </figcaption>
</figure>
```

### Interaction on images

Apparently, the images can be clicked, probably to enlarge them.

Any functionality that works on click, also needs to work with a keyboard, and needs an accessible name. Native, interactive elements like `<button>` do that by default. An image does not.

So you’d either use a wrapping button, or add `tabindex` and [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event) manually, as well as explaining the action in the accessible name, which is provided through the `alt` attribute.

```
<script>
const imgKey = e => ['Enter', ' '].includes(e.key) ? alert('click') : false;
</script>
…

<img tabindex="0" onkeydown="imgKey(event)" onclick="displayLightBox(243, 95234343, 'Mimi')" src="./assets/media/Mimi/Animals_Rainbow.jpg" alt="Rainbow Bird. Enlarge">
```

### Interaction on videos

`<video controls>` itself is already a component with controls inside. Hence, the parent must not have an interaction bound to it. It conflicts with a click (or keyboard interaction) on the video’s controls.

Instead, add an additional button, maybe next to the like button.

```
<video controls>
…
</video>

<button aria-label="Enlarge video Wild horses in the mountains" onclick="displayLightBox(243, 5234343, 'Mimi')">Enlarge</button>
```

Or, you rely on the *fullscreen* button which is part of the controls.